# Pass result from confirmation message to spring mvc controller

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have a project assignment in spring mvc and I have a function to delete an element from the table and I want to implement a confirmation for the action.

I don't have experience in js , I saw this code in w3schools but failed to implement it so it can work for me.

```
JSP:
<td><a href="${deleteUrl}" onclick="deleteConfirm()">Delete</a></td>
<script>
    function deleteConfirm(){
        var confirmation = confirm("Do you really want to delete this item 
    from the list?");
        if(confirmation===false){
            var message = "false";
            return message;
        }
    }
 </script>


Controller : 
@GetMapping(Mappings.ITEMS)
public String booksList(Model model,HttpServletRequest request){
 String message = request.getAttribute("message").toString();
    if(message.equals("false")){
        return "redirect:/home";
    } else {
        delete elemtn ..
        ...
    }
  }
```

Any sources I can check for that matter?

Comment: You need ajax. You can also look into jquery ajax or fetch api. Take a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-4-mvc-ajax-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you call the URL `${deleteUrl}` handled with the controller, the deletion happens regardless of the confirmation pop-up.

In JavaScript, you have to bound the text/link/button in a table with a function, that does the following:

1. Open a pop-up and **then**...
2. Call the URL with the AJAX upon confirmation.

Let's for sake of brevity use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) which I find as a very powerful library. The simplest piece of code I can construct would look like:

```
function confirmDelete(url) {
    var result = confirm("Do you want to delete an entry?");      
    if (result) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "DELETE",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : url,
            timeout : 10000,
            success : function(data) {
                // update the table
            },
            error : function(e) {
                // handle the error
            }
        });
    }
}
```